# Need help solving Python assignment

Tags: python

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to solve a problem using the lambda function and dictionary. The problem calls for importing a text file that has many first and last names, and printing out the names using the lambda function to print 'Hello first_name last_name'. Below is what I have so far to start off with but I can't figure out how to add the first and last name into the dictionary since the file has different length of first and last names formatted as ex.(Christian Anderson) or (Beau Bates). I'm not sure if dictionary allows a ' ' as a slicing method.

```
names_file = open('names.txt')
actual_num_lines = len(names_file.readlines())
names_file.close()

names_file = open('names.txt')
names_list = names_file.read().split('\n')
#using a dictionary
names_dict = {}

for i in range(0, len(actual_num_lines)):
    first = names_list[i][0:' ']
    last = names_list[i][' ':]
    names_dict[first] = last

print(names_dict.items())
```

Comment: Please look at this first:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

StackOverflow is not a place where you can crowdsource people to do your homework for you for free. You have to first demonstrate what you tried, or explain specifically what you don't understand. This question just seems like you want someone to do your homework.

Comment: @vasia Sorry that you took it that way. I have some code that I started on for the question but I have a hard time formatting the code on this website which is why i just posted to question instead.

Comment: The long list of names that you've provided in the question are not helpful, they don't provide any useful context to someone who would potentially answer your question. I would:
1) remove the names from the question
2) summarize the problem you are trying to solve in the question post itself (dont make people click a link to an image to read your entire problem)
3) describe what you've tried, what you don't understand, or where you're stuck. 

If you want someone to put effort into an answer, you have to put effort into the question.

Comment: @vasia my bad I will fix that. It's only my second time on here so I wasn't sure how everything works.

Comment: You can also check this page for additional guidance https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask